# (IndexError: list assignment index out of range) error index array

Tags: python, arrays

PYTHON

I attribute the value 0  in the position tam+1 of array, but happens the same error "IndexError: list assignment index out of range ", and i don't know why.

My code is bellow:

```
 from math import sqrt as s

 Tam = 3
 soma = 0

 R = [Tam + 2]
 G = [Tam + 2]
 B = [Tam + 2]

 Rf = [Tam]
 Gf = [Tam]
 Bf = [Tam]

dist = [Tam]

R[0] = 0
R[Tam + 1] = 0
G[0] = 0
G[Tam + 1] = 0
B[0] = 0
B[Tam + 1] = 0
```

And showed this:

```
File "exer1.py", line 17, in <module>                                                                                     
R[Tam + 1] = 0                                                                                                      
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

### What's wrong

In your code, you refer to `R[Tam + 1]` which is the line giving the error. Earlier, you define `Tam` as equal to 3, and `R` as equal to `[Tam + 2]`, which produces a list that holds one element, `Tam + 2`, or, since you previously defined `Tam`, 5. In other words, `R` is a list that holds a single element, 5.

Next, you try to reference a specific element in `R` - `Tam + 1`, or 4. You would have to have five elements in `R` for `R[4]` to exist, so it returns an error, `IndexError`, because the index you have provided does not lead to a proper element.

### Possible fixes

To fix this, we have to know exactly what you want to do here. If you wanted to *add* the element `Tam + 1` to the list, you would do `R.append(Tam + 1)`. If you wanted to set the fourth element in the list equal to zero, you would do `R[Tam + 1] = 0`; however, there is no fourth element in the list to set equal to zero.

### Some stylistic notes

These aren't necessary to fix your program, but you might want to read through PEP8, the style guide for python. In particular, I note that you're importing a package you don't need (though of course you might need it later in your program; I don't know), you're defining variables with single-letter uppercase names, when ideally you'd use a longer more descriptive name. You also have names like `Rf`, when ideally it would be `r_f` (and more descriptive). You may also wish to add comments to your code to explain what is going on. These changes will make it easier for others and yourself to read your code and find problems or add to the code.

Comment: @Leticia.M you may want to read through a tutorial like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp), as python, while it shares some similarities with C, is a very different language.

Comment: Thanks for the explication, really helped. I trying pass a code in C for python:


int R[Tam + 2];

R[0] = 0;
R[Tam + 1] = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Python list assignment does not work in the way you think it does.

When you assign a list, you do in the below fashion.

```
my_list = [element_1, element_2, element_3, ...]
```

Whereas you are using the (made up) syntax.

```
my_list = [size_of_list]
```

---

Now you know this, I have faith you can give your code another go.

Comment: Thank you! I understanded now how to attribute a value inside list. But not clear how a i put the value in a specific position

Comment: @Leticia.M That basically just isn't really how Python lists are meant to work. You need to escape the way of thinking that says: I initialise my list then assign elements *where* I want them and instead think in terms of I have an empty list and I am going to populate it with the *values* that I want, using `.append` etc. Yes, once you have many elements in your lists, you can index them with `my_list[index]`, but you should populate it with useful data first. If you really want a C-like array, look at `numpy`. You should also find a guide on Python! :)